# Change color of bar plot in Python

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I have three sets of histogram plot displayed by group. In this setting, I would like to differentiate each group by color[image].

For example, cubicle - red, hallway - blue, office - green. Any advice?

Here's my current code:

```
df_mean['mean'].hist(by=df_mean['type'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing color parameter to hist?

```
plt.hist(x, color='r')
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried it. However, it does not differentiate each label. I want different color for each group.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a color for each histogram after you have created the figure with [`df.hist()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html), like in this example:

```
import numpy as np                 # v 1.19.2
import pandas as pd                # v 1.1.3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    # v 3.3.2

# Create random dataset
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=12345) # random number generator
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(area_type = np.repeat(['cubicle', 'hallway', 'office'], [9, 10, 12]),
                       mean = np.append(rng.uniform(low=100, high=1400, size=9),
                                        rng.exponential(scale=500, size=22))))

# Plot grid of histograms using pandas df.hist (note that df.plot.hist
# does not produce the same result, it seems to ignore the 'by' parameter)
grid = df['mean'].hist(by=df['area_type'])
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green']

# Loop through axes contained in grid and list of colors
for ax, color in zip(grid.flatten(), colors):
    # Loop through rectangle patches representing the histogram contained in ax
    for patch in ax.patches:
        patch.set_color(color)

# Change size of figure
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(8, 6)

plt.show()
```

[image: pandas_hist_color1]

Instead of manually picking colors, you could also pick colors automatically from a chosen [colormap](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) (in this case a qualitative colormap is appropriate), like this:

```
# Select colormap properties
cmap_name = 'Accent' # enter any colormap name (see whole list by running plt.colormaps())
ncolors = df['area_type'].nunique()

# Extract list of colors that span the entire gradient of the colormap
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap(cmap_name)
colors = cmap(np.linspace(0, 1, ncolors))

# Create plot like in previous example
grid = df['mean'].hist(by=df['area_type'])
for ax, color in zip(grid.flatten(), colors):
    for patch in ax.patches:
        patch.set_color(color)
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(8, 6)
plt.show()
```

[image: pandas_hist_color2]